# argument in theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I want to add pad to make the output shape be equal to the input shape when using theano.tensor.nnet.con2d.

```
conv_Out = conv2d(
                input = input_Re,
                filters = self.W,
                filter_shape = filter_Shape,
                border_mode = (pad_C,pad_R),
                #border_mode = 'half'
                subsample = stride)
```

If border_mode = (pad_C,pad_R),there is error like "not all arguments converted during string formatting".
If border_mode = 'half', there is error like "Mode half not implemented".
If border_mode is equal to default, everything is OK.

What's wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Tough luck, if you take a look at the source code of `theano.tensor.nnet.con2d` you'll see it does not support padding or the 'half' option at all, as opposed to what is claimed in the current documentation.

I use `theano.sandbox.cuda.dnn.dnn_conv` instead, it supports padding.